# Firebase adding collaborators to project who only have access to Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi I've had a firebase project in production for a while now and we're now having to do a bunch of work with the authentication system and I would like to give someone access to JUST the authentication system and read only permissions to the database. In summary they should be able to look up if a user exists in authentication, delete them if desired, and be able to look them up in the database. Obviously this is done with adding a project member. I'm running into issues because I can't figure out what roles to give them. There's no "Authentication Admin" or something similar. Can someone tell me what role would give them this desired access? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no granular control for permissions and access for the various parts of the Firebase console.  If this is something you'd like to see, please [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with the specifics.